# Custom segue causes navigation item to disappear

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I'm using custom segues with no animation because I don't like the animation of the default segue. The problem is that in the storyboard, when I flip the segue style from Push to Custom, the view controller's navigation item disappears. Now, it seems that the navigation item still works even if the segue is set to Custom, but that means constantly flipping back and forth between Push and Custom when changes need to be made.

Is there any way to use a custom segue and still have IB access to the navigation item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, select the view controller and open the attributes inspector.  Then change the "Top Bar" from "Inferred" to "Navigation Bar".  That should keep the navigation bar displayed.